# How to update Resque to clear data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque-scheduler

I am uncertain why I have old data when I have just dropped by database & reseeded with new data. The old data is tied to a Resque job and I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It is using Redis? If yes, that is your answer.

You can clean all Resque queues following this command:

`Resque.queues.each { |q| Resque.redis.del "queue:#{q}" }`